# Существуют ли генераторы (фабрики) функций?

Tags: python, property, классы

Дано: класс с десятком полей.
Необходимо: с помощью встроенного декоратора `@property` преобразовать каждое поле в свойство т.е.

```
class Static:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs)

        if 'today' in kwargs:
            self.today = kwargs['today']
        else:
            self.today = datetime.date.today()
        //поля в таком-же стиле т.е. разная статика

    @property
    def today(self):
        return self.today

    @today.setter
    def today(self,value):
        self.today = value

    @today.deleter
    def today(self):
        del self.today
```

и так с каждым полем.
В результате очень много дублирующегося кода.

Суть вопроса: существует - ли более красивое/питоновское(Пайтоновское) решение или все это оформить в отдельном файле как есть?

Возможно, существуют "Генераторы(фабрики) функций(методов)" или декораторы, или неизвестное мне решение?

Интересуют идеи, мысли и личный опыт

Спасибо ReinRaus - Решение простое и гениальное.
O_o и тут я понял как-же мало я знаю
Cсылка рано или поздно станет битой, с Вашего разрешения, выложу код здесь

Вопрос решен.

```
props={}
def myProp(fn):
    props[fn.__name__]=fn

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=5
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in props.keys():
            return props[name](self)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    def __delattribute__(self, name):
        if name in props.keys():
            del props[name]
            return
        object.__delattribute__(self, name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in props.keys():
            return props[name](self, value)
        return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    @myProp
    def myfunc(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.x=value*2
        return self.x-2

x= test()
print(x.myfunc)
x.myfunc=6
print(x.myfunc)
```

Comment: Пока как-то так:  
http://ideone.com/Y5HYEn  
Я посплю, а Вы потестируйте, вечером исправлю скрытые ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но это не то. вечером отпишусь, почему.

Comment: А нельзя ли из соображений уменьшения количества `boilerplate` кода воспользоваться [функцией `property`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406567/preferred-way-of-defining-properties-in-python-property-decorator-or-lambda)? Добавите необходимое количество лямбда-выражений для `setter'ов` и `deleter'ов` и сделаете всю эту инициализацию в одном месте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Языком это не предусмотрено.
Можно попробовать сделать свою форму записи. Я реализовал в такой форме:

```
@myProp
def propName(self, value=None):
    if value:
        ... # это setter
    return ...# это геттер
```

Реализация здесь:
http://ideone.com/Y5HYEn
У меня не получилось навести красоту: внести массив props в сам класс, потому что на момент компиляции декораторов класса test не существует, поэтому я вынес этот массив в глобальный.

---

**Некроправка**
Захотел сделать себе так же, но предварительно навел небольшую красоту, теперь просто есть класс, который нужно унаследовать.

```
class test(myProp):

@myProp.wrapper
def myfunc(self, value=None):
    if value:
        # setter
    return # getter
```

Полный код:
http://ideone.com/ZsOF5z

```
class myProp:
    __props={}
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in object.__getattribute__(self, "_myProp__props").keys():
            return self.__props[name](self)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    def __delattribute__(self, name):
        if name in self.__props.keys():
            del self.__props[name]
            return
        object.__delattribute__(self, name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__props.keys():
            return self.__props[name](self, value)
        return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    @classmethod
    def wrapper(self, fn):
        self.__props[fn.__name__]=fn

class test(myProp):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=5

    @myProp.wrapper
    def myfunc(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.x=value*2
        return self.x-2
```

Answer (score 3):

Предложу альтернативу.
Property может быть и не декоратором вовсе.

**UPD**

Я тут подумал. Мне ведь никто не мешает использовать синтаксис декораторов для оборачивания класса.

**UPD2**

Ну и никто не мешает запихать служебную функцию make_prop поглубже.

```
def set_props(prop_names):
    def makeprop(container_name):
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, container_name)
        def setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, container_name, value)
        def deleter(self):
            delattr(self, container_name)
        return property(getter, setter, deleter)
    def wrapper(cl):
        props = map(lambda x: makeprop('_' + x), prop_names)
        for prop_name, prop in zip(prop_names, props):
            setattr(cl, prop_name, prop)
        return cl
    return wrapper

@set_props(('today',))
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.today = kwargs.get('today', datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно. Сохраню ссылочку сюда.